# Adding an error check to VBA code that generates named ranges

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges

I have been using the following code to generate named ranges for datasets with a large number of columns

```
Sub Make_Named_Ranges()

Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.UsedRange

Dim rCell2 As Range
Dim wb2 As Workbook, ws2 As Worksheet

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
Set ws2 = Selection.Parent
Set wb2 = ws2.Parent

For Each rCell2 In Selection.Cells

If rCell2.Address = "$A$2" Then Exit For

wb2.Names.Add rCell2.Value, "=" & ws2.Cells(2, rCell2.Column).Address  
& _":" & ws2.Cells(ActiveSheet.Range("A"&   Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row,rCell2.Column).Address

Next rCell2
End Sub
```

What I would like to add is a form of error checking - occassionally the code encounters a column heading in row 1 that isn't a valid name (e.g., M2 or SP500). Is there a simple way to have it just skip this column and keep going when it encounters an invalid name?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to change the error handling.  Include this code immediately before the line(s) of code that generates the error:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

This code instructs the script to ignore any errors generated from that point on.  If an error occurs, no error message will be generated and the script will continue to the next line of code.

Turn error handling back on for the rest of the script by adding this immediately after the line(s) generating the error:

```
On Error Goto 0
```

There are better ways of dealing with errors but this is probably the easiest to use.